# Django: ForeignKey Filter Selected Data Query in Form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am working with automated result system app.I have five models class in models.py file.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    std_name=models.CharField('Student Name ', max_length=200)
    CLASS_NAME=(
        ('6','SIX'),
        ('7','SEVEN'),
        ('8','Eight'),
        ('9','Nine'),
        ('10','Ten'),
        ('Ex-10','EX-Ten'),
    )
    std_class_name=models.CharField('Class Name', max_length=7, choices=CLASS_NAME)
    std_roll_number=models.IntegerField('Roll Number')
    GENDER=(
        ('Male','Male'),
        ('Female','Female'),
    )
    std_gender=models.CharField('Gender', max_length=7, choices=GENDER)
    GROUP=(
        ('Science','Science Group'),
        ('B.Studies','Business Group'),
        ('Arts and Humatics','Arts and Humatics'),
        ('General','General'),
    )
    std_group=models.CharField('Group', max_length=17, choices=GROUP)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)
    std_total_subject=models.IntegerField('Total Subject', default=0)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.std_name



class ExaminationName(models.Model):
    examination_name=models.CharField('Examination Name ', max_length=100)
    exam_date=models.DateTimeField('Exam Date: ')
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.examination_name

class MainSubject(models.Model):
    main_subject_name = models.CharField('Main Subject Name', max_length=100)
    main_subject_code=models.DecimalField('Main Subject Code', decimal_places=0, default=0, max_digits=10)
    subject_full_marks = models.DecimalField('Subject Full Marks', max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, default=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.main_subject_name



class SubjectName(models.Model):
    mainsubject = models.ForeignKey(MainSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_name=models.CharField('Subject Name', max_length=100)
    subject_full_marks=models.DecimalField('Subject Full Marks',max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, default=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)

    subject_gpa_point=models.DecimalField('GPA in Subject',max_digits=4, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    subject_gpa_grade=models.CharField('GPA Grade',max_length=5, default='F')


    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_name


class SubjectPart(models.Model):
    mainsubject = models.ForeignKey(MainSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjectname = models.ForeignKey(SubjectName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_part_name=models.CharField('Subject Part', max_length=100)
    subject_part_full_marks = models.DecimalField('Full Marks', max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, default=100)
    subject_part_pass_marks = models.DecimalField('Pass Marks', max_digits=6, decimal_places=0, default=100)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.subject_part_name






class AddResult(models.Model):
    student=models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    examinationname = models.ForeignKey(ExaminationName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    mainsubject_name = models.ForeignKey(MainSubject, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjectname = models.ForeignKey(SubjectName, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subjectpart = models.ForeignKey(SubjectPart, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    subject_number=models.DecimalField('Subject Number', max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('Published', auto_now_add=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.subjectpart)

    def fail_sub(self):
        if self.subject_number < self.subjectpart.subject_part_pass_marks:
            return 'F'
```

I have created a MainSubject object via Django admin panel. I added main subject within SubjectName Model class via foreignkey. 
I creaated two foreign key within SubjectName model class. I created any object within SubjectPart model via Django-admin panel like this.

[image]

Then I created a AddResulForm ModelForm. But Problem is When I chose Subject Name, all subject show that time. If I select Bangla as Main subject, then I chose only Bangla First Part or Bangla 2nd Part within Subject Name Part. But Now showed all subject in this form. 
How Can I implement my idea in Django forms?

Comment: -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671446/country-state-city-dropdown-menus-inside-the-django-admin-inline
-  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917893/django-admin-displaying-a-hierarchical-dropdown-filter

these two answer might help you.

and please let me know if you still have doubts.

Answer (score 1):

**for that, you should write methods in admin.py**

you can create a class for the model(Subject Part) and implement a method for the field.

you can refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/

Answer (score 0):

In Django you  can filter choice set,But front-end  interaction，you may have to reimplement form template html code or form field.